# Is there a way to get 3+ dimensional array from a single MySql command

Tags: php, mysql

For example an array that has all the months, inside each month are all the users registered that month, and details on every user. I could solve it by simply searching for all users registered this year, then put the results through a loop that builds the array I want by detecting when there is a change in the 6th and 7th characters of the "date" field (example: 2016-04-05), but I am wondering if there is a more "official" way.

Comment: Why do you need to detect changes to the month in user registration dates? Registration dates don't change...

Comment: @bosco I meant change between different users. When the current user's month is different than the previous one the code would start assigning the users to a new field of the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The direct answer to the question *"Is there a way to get 3+ dimensional array from a single MySql command"* would be **yes, sort of** - WordPress routinely stores and retrieves multidimensional data from MySQL rows by `serialize()`ing and `unserialize()`ing structured data to/from a string format, so it's certainly possible using WordPress's database interaction mechanisms. The [Metadata API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Metadata_API) automatically handles this process when you pass it structured data, for example.

However, your question is rather something more along the lines of *"How can I restructure database results into a custom format?"*

The most "WordPress-y" way would be as you describe - use a `WP_User_Query` to query for users then re-arrange the results into your desired structure.

It may be possible to create a custom SQL query that formats the results as you desire but it seems counter-intuitive - relational databases are designed with a large emphasis on 2-dimensional data. Inquire over at [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com) if you'd be interested in such a query. You can execute custom queries in WordPress using the `parse_query()` method of `WP_Query`.

To acquire a structure of users who registered within a certain year grouped by month of registration, I would do the following:

```
function wpse225632_get_users_by_reg_month( $year = null ) {
  $args = array();

  if( isset( $year ) )
    $args[ 'date_query' ] = array( 'year' => $year );

  $users          = get_users( $args );
  $users_by_month = array();

  foreach( $users as $user ) {
    $reg_month = mysql2date( 'm', $user->user_registered );

    if( ! isset( $users_by_month[ $reg_month ] ) )
      $users_by_month[ $reg_month ] = array();

    $users_by_month[ $reg_month ][] = $user;
  }

  return $users_by_month;
}
```

If you'll be running this query frequently, you may wish to cache the resulting array using the [Transients API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API), then invalidate the cache and delete the transient whenever a new user is registered.